# Quote Parameter for Facebook Share method no longer working?

Tags: facebook, share, quote

Per Facebook dev documentation, the share parameter "quote" should insert text:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/

This seemed to be working the other week, but now even using their own testing tool ( http://www.fbrell.com/Sharing/2%20-%20FB.ui%20Dialogs?fbclid=IwAR2TX_eOex-HmIqbIfz9sakxN_laCAVVW_g6p-dW54WwVZkXQ_u5VZi8OCE ), the quote parameter doesn't seem to be inserting any text into the share dialog that pops up.

Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: File a bug in the Facebook Developer bug tracker.

Comment: Bug report for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/734680371318112/

Comment: the 'hashtag' props is still working?

Answer (score 5):

Someone from the Meta team has said "[the quote feature has been deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/734680371318112/?comment_id=743056360480513)". The documentation had still not been updated at that time, though.

Pretty weird for them to remove a feature with no warning or update to their documentation, then call it "deprecated" (which typically refers to a feature that still works but will be removed in the future).

Answer (score 2):

same problem for me

```
  FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        href: this.location,
        quote: this.description
      })
```

It worked a week ago, but now it doesn't. but the Facebook documentation does not mention anything about this change

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgSA0.png

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://my-url',
    quote: encodeURIComponent('My quote')
  }
);
```