# Alternate Solutions for Quote Parameter for Facebook Share method

Tags: facebook, share, quote

The quote parameter to insert text per Facebook dev documentation is no longer working.

I am reaching out to other developers who may have encountered this issue to ask if you have found any alternatives? What have you been doing to mitigate the removal of this feature?

.
.
.

Additional threads on the issue:

Stack Overflow: [Quote Parameter for Facebook Share method no longer working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72550383/quote-parameter-for-facebook-share-method-no-longer-working)

Facebook Dev Bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/734680371318112/?join_id=f381df531e78ecc